# read_csv to define col_types text to numeric. Values with format "suffix-<num>" change to -ve num

Tags: r, csv, format, readr

I am new to R and new to the data analysis. For my very first task,I used read::read_csv() and used col_types to indicate the format. For the ID column that is supposed to be numeric I chose 'n'.

I used the code below

```
data_2023_04 <- read_csv("data_2023_04.csv",trim_ws=TRUE,col_types="ccTTcncnddddc",show_col_types=TRUE)
```

I expected all text will be replaced by "na" but non numeric values that contained suffix changed to negative numeric value (e.g. LF-005 ==> -5).

Is there a mean to stop read_csv() from removing just suffix?
In general, is it advised to use read_csv to enforce variable type?

Comment: Seems like read_csv is doing some guessing there. Probably safer to read that column as character and convert to numeric using as.numeric() afterwards. That should result in "LF-005" turning to "NA", but "0005" to 5.

Comment: Thank you @Where'smytowel !!! I tried your proposal it solved my problem.